# how to convert json file to image using node js

Tags: node.js

```
node.js:

var express = require("express");
var myParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();

app.use(myParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
app.get("/",function(req,res){
res.send("Welcome");
});

app.post("/sendmessage", function(request, response) {
//console.log(request.body); 

var jsonData = request.body;
console.log(jsonData);
var jsonContent = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
// Get Value from JSON
//console.log(jsonContent.text);
var data = jsonContent.text;
//  console.log(data);

//DB Connection
//createConnection(data);

response.send("Data Received");
});
var server = app.listen(8080, function () {
var host = "10.0.0.5"; 
var port = "8080";

console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port);
});
```

From client i got a json format using node js but i need that json format should be read and display uploaded image without storing in database.

Comment: Show me your json...

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it to `base64` string.

```
var jsonContent = JSON.parse(jsonData);
var buff = new Buffer(jsonContent).toString("base64");
```